# Check if a string contains multiple items, separated by comma or space?

Tags: ruby, string

I want to allow users to input multiple strings, separated by comma or space, and then check if a referring URL contains any of those strings.

For instance, someone may only want a widget to show up on their `/contact, /support, /about` pages.

So then I'd want to do something like this to check if the URL contains any of those strings...

```
ref = "http://example.com/contact"

ref.include?('/contact, /support, /about')
```

Since what we're checking against would be input by the user, ideally the strings could be comma or space-separated.

Comment: Because `ref.include?( ['/contract', '/support', '/about'] )` is too mainstream?

Comment: @Jeffrey Mainstream or not that code will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: @toro2k, if you don't implement it, of course. I haven't said my code is in native Ruby. I said that a list of strings would make more sense to be in an `Array` rather than a `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = "/contact, /support, /about".split(/[,\s]+/)
# => ["/contact", "/support", "/about"]

a.any?{|s| "http://example.com/contact".include?(s)}
# => true
```